# Vector inside a class. C2065 error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class, vector

I have vector of my own objects inside a class. But when i want to do something with this vector, i have error :/
game.h

```
#include "renderSystem.h" //there only  #include "console_color.h"
#include "level.h" //there only #include "renderSystem.h"
#include "gameObject.h"
class Game {
    vector<GameObject> objects;
    //something
public:
    Game();
    //something
};
```

game.cpp

```
void Game::initialize() {
    GameObject playerObject(GameObjectType_Player);
    objects.insert(objects.end(), playerObject);
    //something
}
```

gameObject.h

```
#include "renderSystem.h"
#include "level.h"
class GameObject {
    //something
public:
    GameObject(GameObjectType _type);
    GameObject() : GameObject(GameObjectType_None) {};
    //something
};
```

And errors are (i cant give you logs, because they are on russian :/ )

```
C2065 at game.cpp "objects.insert"
C2143 at game.h "vector<GameObject> objects"
C2228 at game.cpp "objects.insert"
C2238 at game.h "vector<GameObject> objects"
C4430 at game.h "vector<GameObject> objects"
```

I checked #includes, but may be i'm stupid :/
And in every file i have #pragma once
In renderSystem and level i wrote only includes
Wtf?!
Visual studio 2015
//And i have 0:43 AM, so may be i just need to sleep :/

Comment: If you have Russian logs you can post the question with them on StackOverflow.ru

Comment: Ahh, what the difference? I wrote what it need to know, the title of error can be found on msdn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues here, one, you're not including the vector header file. The second is that the vector class is in the std:: namespace in C++. Here are two possible fixes to this.

```
#include <vector> /* STL vector */

#include "renderSystem.h" //there only  #include "console_color.h"
#include "level.h" //there only #include "renderSystem.h"
#include "gameObject.h"

class Game {
private:
    std::vector<GameObject> objects;

public:
    Game();
};
```

Or

```
#include <vector> /* STL vector */

#include "renderSystem.h" //there only  #include "console_color.h"
#include "level.h" //there only #include "renderSystem.h"
#include "gameObject.h"

using namespace std;

class Game {
    vector<GameObject> objects;
    //something
public:
    Game();
    //something
};
```

Comment: Damn it! I forgot abous std >.<